# How to combine several ppp object

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm not sure if it's a meaningful question but I don't understand how (and if) is it possible to combine a list of `ppp` objects into a unique `ppp` object. For example

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.62-2       (nickname: 'Shape-shifting lizard') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'

ppp1 <- ppp(runif(20), runif(20), c(0,1), c(0,1))
ppp2 <- ppp(runif(20), runif(20), c(0,1), c(0,1))

do.call("rbind", list(ppp1, ppp2))
#>      window n  x          y          markformat
#> [1,] List,4 20 Numeric,20 Numeric,20 "none"    
#> [2,] List,4 20 Numeric,20 Numeric,20 "none"
do.call("ppp", list(ppp1, ppp2))
#> Error in ppp(structure(list(window = structure(list(type = "rectangle", : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I think that the result should be a ppp object created by rbinding the coordinates and marks and window object should be the union of the owin objects. Is that a reasonable idea? Is that already coded or documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid question, it's all documented here: https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/superimpose.html.